# Better Performing alternative to CSS filter: blur()

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, html5-canvas, blur

I began working on a react project which heavily utilises blur effect.

It takes the icon added to a div and it puts it as a background and blurs it.

Therefore, every section that has different icon has different colorfull background.

I have attached the image because I believe I explained it poorly:

[image: Screenshot of the website]

I am not sure what part of code to attach so I will put the react component and css affecting it here:

**React Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Object.css';

const Jobs = ({ employer, description, descriptionList, image }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <section className="object-container">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="object">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-sm-8">
                                <h3 className="employer">
                                    {employer}
                                </h3>
                                <div className="description">
                                    {description}
                                </div>
                                <ul className="description-list">
                                    {descriptionList.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div className="image-container">
                                <div className="col-sm-4">
                                    <img className="image" src={image} alt="logo" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="object__bg" id="object__bg" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div >
    );
}

export default Jobs;
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Neon Online';
    src: url(I_am_online_with_u.ttf) format('truetype'),
        url(I_am_online_with_u.woff) format('woff');
  }

.object {
   padding: 40px; 
    background-color: rgba(53, 53, 53, 0.45);
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 28px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
        /* 
        This is used for improving performance with blur filter.
        Why does it work, I have no idea...
     */
     backface-visibility: hidden;
     perspective: 1000;
     transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
     transform: translateZ(0);
}

.object:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 32px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    background-color: rgba(53, 53, 53, 0.55);
    transform: scale(1.01);
    transition: all 0.31s ease-out;
}

.object-container {
    position: relative; 
    padding: 40px;
    /* 
        This is used for improving performance with blur filter.
        Why does it work, I have no idea...
     */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

.object__bg  {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: -10vw;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 120vw;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    filter: blur(150px) saturate(2) hue-rotate(0deg);

    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #353535;

    transition: all 1.5s ease-out;
}

.object__bg:hover,
.object__bg:focus {
    filter: blur(150px) saturate(2.6) hue-rotate(180deg);
    transition: all 3s ease-in;
}


.image-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.image {
 width:  200px;   
}
```

I thought of canvas and svg filters because I read  a few times that it's blur effect improves performance significantly. 
Unfortunately, after trying it a few times I just didn't manage to get it working with React.

I have also tried adding backface visibility to the elements overlaying the blur which helped (probably because it forces GPU to do the work instead of CPU, I am not sure).

So, is there any current alternative that could help me with a website that utilises blur this heavily?

Comment: If the list of possible icons is fixed, you could pre-render the blurs on the server and simply set some background raster images, overlapping and partially transparent.

Comment: A little googling lead me to this: https://github.com/Frondor/js-image-blur. I haven't used it before so I can't speak to its quality.

Comment: @DanielBernardi, I was hoping for  a solution that wouldn't require external plugins, but nevertheless I will give it a shot and let you know